# Can't get JSON data response from Angular 2+ application

Tags: angular

This is the code snippest in my service.ts(this.http is a HttpClient obj)

```
importAllImages (): Observable<Image[]> {
return this.http.get<Image[]>('http://localhost:8080/fileservice/allimages');
}
```

And this is the code snippest that calls the service shown above(filemanager is an obj of the service above and images is an array of image obj):

```
this.fileManager.importAllImages().subscribe(imagesp => this.images = imagesp);
console.log(this.images.length);
```

And my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
<p>{{image?.imageName}}</p>
```

Then i open http://localhost:4200 but i can't get any image names in it.

PS:I have successfully start my backend SpringBoot Application and i can see my JSON data when i open http://localhost:8080 like this:
[JSON Data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0f5E.png)
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The console.log(...) output is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return json, so you need to deserialize the response object to json:

```
importAllImages(): Observable<Image[]> {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/fileservice/allimages')
    .map((response) => {
      return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But after i import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' , the  complier always prompt that property 'json' doesn't exist .What's the reason ?

Comment: Ah you must be on Angular 5, so you don't need .json(). See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005430/property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object

Comment: I have figured out the reason for my error.The code stuck above is right.It's me who miss-spell attribute names in my angular2 project which makes the obj in springboot project is not exactly the same in angular2 . And thanks for your answer , hope no more trouble for you!