# Ionic Angular Uncaught (in promise) error

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to Ionic.

[This](https://wwwlyndacom.ezproxy.mdx.ac.uk/Web-Development-tutorials/Add-SW-provider-via-CLI/562925/615551-4.html) course on Lynda is my introduction to Ionic and I've been following the instructor tutorial successfully until he introduced **providers**. My provider file is as follows:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
  Generated class for the PeopleDataProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PeopleDataProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello PeopleDataProvider Provider');
  }

  getPeople(){
    return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us&seed=d07ade5f51ff3011')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(res => res.results);
  }

}
```

My **home.ts** file is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';
import { PeopleDataProvider } from '../../providers/people-data/people-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [PeopleDataProvider]
})
export class HomePage {

    public people = new Array();
    private detailPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public peopleData:PeopleDataProvider) {

    peopleData.getPeople().subscribe(people => {
      console.log('people',people);
      this.people = people;
    });
    this.detailPage = DetailPage;
  }

  loadDetail(person){
    console.log(person);
    this.navCtrl.push(this.detailPage, {person:person});
  }

}
```

When the app loads I receive the following error:

> Typescript Error
>
> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>
> src/providers/people-data/people-data.ts
>
> return
>   this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us&seed=d07ade5f51ff3011')
>   .map(res => res.json()) .map(res => res.results);

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005430/property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post suggested the introduction of `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` as the solution.

However, that import does not fix the issue for me.

**Extra complication:**

The error changes to the following exception after a couple of refreshes to the browser but I can't predict when nor control when it occures:

> ionic Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PeopleDataProvider -> HttpClient]:

I don't know if the two errors are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `map` and call `.json` on the response, those are required only when you are using the old [`Http`](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) instead of [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http).

So your method should be like this

**PeopleDataProvider**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
..
getPeople(){
    return this.http.get<any>('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us&seed=d07ade5f51ff3011')
    .map(res => res.results);
}
```

As for the following error,

> ionic Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PeopleDataProvider -> HttpClient]:

Make sure you have imported `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`.

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ .. , HttpClientModule],
  ..
})
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-2882)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Can you direct me at the best resource I can refer to which would help me know what has and hasn't been deprecated? It's clear the tutorial I'm following is dated.

Comment: I suggest you refer the [official angular](https://angular.io) documentation, deprecated APIs are flagged, for example check this [`Http`](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) doc

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using HttpClient its obvious u are using Angular 4.3+. After this version .map amd .json() has been removed..
try this---

```
 getPeople(){
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us&seed=d07ade5f51ff3011');
```

}

Remove--

```
.map(res => res.json())
.map(res => res.results);
```