# angular and http does not understand json - Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular

I just upgraded my angular to v7.

How this happens:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
};

var url = this.getEndpointUrl(endpoint);

return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
```

Getting error:

> [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'. [2339]
>   any

What am I missing?

Comment: have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005430/property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object

Comment: you don't t need the json, res should already be your object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest `HttpClient` automatically parses the response as json so we don't need to call `json()` method anymore.

This should be enough

```
var url = this.getEndpointUrl(endpoint);
return this.http.get(url, httpOptions);
```

Ref: 
https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data