# Unable to map post response Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to setup a service on Angular version 7 but I'm having an issue on `res.json()` which throws the error `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'`. This is my service's code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {
    SVCParameters,
    SVCResult
} from "./types";

const SERVER_URL: string = 'api/';

@Injectable()
export class IrisService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public trainModel(svcParameters: SVCParameters): Observable<SVCResult> {
        return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}train`, svcParameters).pipe(map(res => res.json()));

    }
}
```

The following is my types.ts code:

```
export class SVCParameters {
C: number = 2.0;
}

export class SVCResult{
accuracy: number;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `map`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005430/property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: In the new HttpClient (Angular 4.3+), the response object is JSON by default, so you don't need to do response.json() anymore. Just use response directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 7 HttpClientModule, by default returns response as **`JSON`**, there's no need to map the response as `res.json()` just remove your pipe operator. Everything will work fine.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {
    SVCParameters,
    SVCResult
} from "./types";

const SERVER_URL: string = 'api/';

@Injectable()
export class IrisService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public trainModel(svcParameters: SVCParameters): Observable<SVCResult> {
        return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}train`, svcParameters);

    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error instead: 
Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SVCResult>'.   The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?     Property 'accuracy' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type 'SVCResult'.

Comment: try `any`, if everything works fine, then try to figure out which type is suited and whether the response has all the properties of the type or not.

Comment: I've replaced 'Observable<SVCResult>' with 'any' and the error is gone. I really hope this is what I'm supposed to do because I'm just learning Angular.

Comment: @ChristopherKinyua its not