# Cannot find module '@angular/http/src/static_response' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I'm getting an error `Cannot find module '@angular/http/src/static_response' or its corresponding type declarations` from my Angular v12 project when I try to use the import statement in my code: `import { Response } from "@angular/http/src/static_response";`. This statement was working perfectly fine in my Angular v4 project:

```
 getClientMasterData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(x.getBaseURL() + "/ClientMaster/GetMasterData", this.getHeader.get())
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => <MasterDataModel[]>response.json())
            ,catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

While I know that `http` has been moved to `@angular/common`, I don't see neither `src` folder nor `static_response` file inside `@angular/common`.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do following changes:

1. Replace `import { Response } from "@angular/http/src/static_response";` with `import { HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";`
2. Replace `response: Response` with `response: HttpResponse<MasterDataModel[]>`.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6848923/gourav-pokharkar the last part is giving me an error - 'Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<MasterDataModel[]>'

Comment: @TheInquisitiveCoder Could you please try by removing `.json()` method?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6848923/gourav-pokharkar yes, it works then..but will it give the output in json like the way I need it? no, right?

Comment: @TheInquisitiveCoder as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/46005802/6848923, for `RxJS > 5.5`, `HttpClient` itself deserializes the response, so we don't need to add `.json()` explicitly. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: You're welcome, @TheInquisitiveCoder! Please mark this answer as accepted, so that it'll will help someone having similar issue in the future.