# Property 'colName' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

Property 'colName' does not exist on type 'Object'.
app.GridComponent.ts(7, 27): Error occurs in the template of component GridComponent.

app.Grid.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of gridColumns">
           {{col.colName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr  *ngFor="let colObj of gridData">
       <td *ngFor="let col of gridColumns">
           {{colObj[col.colName]}}
       </td>
     <td>
        <a (click)="SelectGrid(colObj)" href= "">select</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

app.GridComponent.ts

```
import {Component,
        Input,
        Output,
EventEmitter} from  "@angular/core"
@Component({
    selector:"grid-ui",
    templateUrl:"./app.Grid.html"
})
export class GridComponent{
    //for columns names 
    gridColumns: Array<Object> = new Array<Object>
    //grid data
    gridData: Array<Object> = new Array<Object>
     @Input("grid_columns")
    set setGridColumns(_gridColumns:Array<Object>){
       this.gridColumns = _gridColumns;
    }
    @Input("grid_data")
    set setGridData(_gridData:Array<Object>){
        this.gridData = _gridData;
     }
    @Output("grid-selected")
     eventemitter: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

    SelectGrid(_selected:Object){
        this.eventemitter.emit(_selected);
        
    }
}
```

I want to  use input output method in angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript : Property does not exist on type 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338763/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type-object)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add interface and use it instead of type Object:

```
interface HasColName { colName: string }
    
@Component({
   selector:"grid-ui",
   templateUrl:"./app.Grid.html"
})
export class GridComponent{
  //for columns names 
  gridColumns: HasColName[] = [];
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

try to replace `Object` type to `any` type

```
gridColumns: Array<any> = new Array<any>

gridData: Array<any> = new Array<any>

...
```

Comment: The real answer is never "Use `any`"; it is always "Use the actual type of object you need. Doesn't exist? Create it."

Comment: Thanks. This works, however I have one doubt should I replace all object in GridComponent by any ?

Comment: you can do that for all unknown/dynamic object type, like @Heretic Monkey comment, you should declare object type if you can